# How to deal with ftp password in web application in a secure manner

Tags: php, mysql, security, passwords

I'm working on a script (PHP+MySQL) that will let you edit file over FTP. 
What I'm trying to do is when user is logged in and connects to the server I want to memorize ftp password so it can be reused to reconnect to the server transparently (for example when browsing files). 
I don't want to store raw password in database for security reasons. I was thinking about storing password in a cookie with reference to the connection id in the database. But this doesn't sound secure enough either. 
How about storing temporary password entry in a database?

Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Comment: Are you stuck with FTP? There's no way you could use something significantly nicer such as SFTP?

Comment: Have you considered storing it in a PHP session?

Comment: @sarnold No, I'm not stuck with FTP I just mentioned it as an example.

Answer (score 2):

You could try an [asymmetric key system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

1. Generate a public/private pair
2. Give the private key to the user
3. Use the public key to encrypt the password and store it in the database
4. Each time the user does an action, they supply the private key you gave them
5. You use the private key to decrypt the password, do the action, and then destroy the private key in memory

Should be more secure then just relying on the server to encrypt/decrypt it on it's own. It's not 100% foolproof (if they root your server, they can sniff the private keys) but it's a good way to prevent a one-sided attack. At least, any old passwords are not vulnerable if you are compromised since the private keys will have been lost.

**Edit:** As has been pointed out by sarnold, you can also do this with a [symmetric key system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm).

Comment: I deleted the comment already. Sorry, I thought you meant using the same symmetric key for all users. My idea was each user would get a different private key.

Comment: So after successful connection to the server user will have to enter private key every time they want to change directory?

Comment: You give the user the private key in a cookie. Each time they connect, their browser will pass it back.